# Do we need to prove that if x∉A in proposition "if A⊆B then A⋃B=B"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

we translate "if $A⊆B$ then $A⋃B=B$" to $$∀x( ( x∈A → x∈B) → ((x∈A ∨ x∈B) ↔ (x∈B)))$$

My work:
we need to prove $A⋃B⊆B$ first.

1) $∀x( x∈A → x∈B)$ (given)

2)$x∈A$

3)$x∈A$ ∨ $x∈B$  --- (addition laws)

4)$x∈B$ ∨ $x∈B$  --- (1,3 implication)

5)$x∈B$ ---(Idempotent laws)

6)($x∈A$ ∨ $x∈B$) → ($x∈B$) ---(3,5condition proof)

7)$∀x((x∈A$ ∨ $x∈B$) → ($x∈B$)) ---(universal generalization)

then we proved that $A⋃B⊆B$.

we need to prove $B⊆A⋃B$.

1)$x∈B$

2)$x∈B ∨ x∈A$ --- (addition laws)

3)$x∈B → (x∈B ∨ x∈A)$ ---(1,3 condition proof)

4)$∀x(x∈B → (x∈B ∨ x∈A)$) ---(universal generalization)

then we proved that $B⊆A⋃B$.

Therefore, $A⋃B=B$ when $x∈A$.

However,what if $x∉A$?

The statement $( x∈A → x∈B)$ still hold true if $x∉A$ ,should i also prove that when $x∉A$ ,it will not make the consequence $((x∈A ∨ x∈B) ↔ (x∈B))$ be false?

There are two possibility for $∀x( ( x∈A → x∈B) )$:

$x∉A → x∈B$ (because F → T = T)

$x∉A → x∉B$ (because F → F = T)

Actually,Do we need to prove these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\not\in A$, then your consequence become
$$(\text{False }\vee x\in B) ↔  (x\in B)$$
Which become the trivial
$$(x\in B) ↔  (x\in B)$$

Comment: holy,it is so obvious i can't even notice that

Comment: I have new thought on this question,is it possible to use direct prove instead of using proof by cases to prove it?
lets say x∉A→x∈B(F→T=T)
1.x∉A→x∈B
2.x∉A
3.x∈B (using 1)
...then what should we do?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : " if A then B" only means " ***in case it ever happened A to be true,*** in that case B would also be true". It makes no claim as to whether A is actually true or not.

---

Suppose you have to prove : (A-->B) ==> C ( I use " ==>" as the " logical implication" symbol).

***First observation*** : you're not asked to prove that (A-->B) is true. You do not even care about knowing whether (A--> B) is true. What you are supposed to do is to show that in any possible  scenario where (A-->B) is true ( be it the case or not in " real life") proposition C cannot be false.

Note : you may say " what if there is no possible scenario where (A--> B) is true?". In that case C would follow vacuously from (A-->B). A truth table will show this; set (A-->B) false in all possible cases, set C true in one case and false in the other one, and compute the truth value of the whole conditional in every case. You will find that the whole conditional is always true.

***Second observation***. When you consider your hypothesis, that is, a " scenario" where (A--> B) is true, *you do not care about knowing whether A is true or not*. Your hypothesis in not proposition A by itself , your hypothesis is the whole consitional (A--> B). It means, so to say, that *there is an hypothesis in the hypothesis, or, if you prefer, a scenario in the scenario*. So the proof has to begin this way :

" SUPPOSE  we are in a situation ( first scenario) where , IN CASE A is true ( second scenario) , B is also true ... What would follow?"

Example. Suppose a person says " If *x is a man* implies *x is a primate,* then ethics is meaningless". Wouild it be relevant to say : " but, what if  *x is a man* is false"? We are asked to put ourselves in a scenario where being a man implies being a primate; and to determine whether , in this situation, the consequence " *ethics is meaningless*" actually follows or not.